# Checksum generation with the same algorithm returns different output

Tags: java

I have two programs, with the same identical checksum generation method(SHA-256).
The difference is, that in the first program the path is (windowspath/folder/file), in the second one the path is (./folder/file).
Here is the code:

**Program 1**

```
String address = fileAddr.getText();
                            File file = new File(address);
                            try
                                {
                                    checksum = getChecksum(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                    data = generateByte(address);

                                }
                            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e1)
                                {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

**Checksum Generation Method**

```
public static String getChecksum(Serializable object) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
            System.out.println(object.toString());
            try
                {
                    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                    oos.writeObject(object);
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(baos.toByteArray());
                    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(thedigest);
                }
            finally
                {
                    oos.close();
                    baos.close();
                }
        }
```

**Program 2**

```
File folder = new File(".\\Plugins");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
listChecksum.add(getChecksum(listOfFiles[i].getPath()));
```

The problem is as described in the title, the two checksums don't correspond.

Comment: Do you even know how hash generation work? Sorry if I sound arrogant but hashes (so also hashes made with SHA-256) are meant to be always the same with the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are not reading the content of the file, just comparing the file names. And these differ for sure, so you get different checksum values.

I would suggest to read the content of the file in the function which generates the checksum:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Path x = Paths.get("D:\\work\\some.zip");
        System.out.println(getChecksum(x));
    }

    public static String getChecksum(Path path) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytes);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(thedigest);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well what can I do to fix this then?